# CSS for sub-menu on navigation bar not working

Tags: html, css, firebug

I am working on a site and have created a navigation bar with sub-items but I am not getting these sub-items display on hover.
Here's my HTML and CSS code for the navigation bar:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="spi-primary-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li id="menu-item-9265" class="home-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9001 current_page_item menu-item-9265">
             <a href="index.html">Home</a>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-9004" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9004 ">
             <a href="Default.aspx">Store</a>
             <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>      
     </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS is here:

```
.navbar-nav > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.navbar-nav > li > ul:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Here is the live link of the site in case someone wants to inspect the elements using Firebug:
http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/Home

Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

You got your `:hover` in the wrong place.
It should be in the `li` instead of the `ul`

Try this instead:

```
.navbar-nav > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: i tried but its not working.. can you please inspect this issue with firebug ?

Comment: I do see the submenu when I hover over `Store` albeit improperly styled

Comment: As kei said it's working when you add that rule. To test that out in Firebug switch to the [*CSS* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/CSS_Panel), right-click it and choose *New Rule...*. Then add the selector, press `Tab`, add `display` as property name, press `Tab` again, and enter `block` as value.

Comment: @SebastianZartner its not working in IE browser but working fine on other browsers..can you please check it what i have missed on ie?
http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/Home

Comment: @kei your suggested css not working with IE browser? any thing missing?

Comment: I did check it on IE 10 and above but did not check it on below v10.

Comment: Can you please check it on IE10 ?